# How do I ignore transparency when quantizing in ImageMagick like image editors do?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I'm trying to reduce the number of colors in a png while ignoring the alpha channel to produce results similar to what I'd get in Photoshop or GIMP. I've read the ImageMagick [quantize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/) page, and tried out the various options it goes over to little success. ImageMagick continues to mess with the transparency even when I use the TransparentColorspace (-transparent) when quantizing.

[Album of Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGlhM.jpg)

Results similar to the second image are what I'm aiming for, which is what the first looks like after reducing the colors to 4 in GIMP (the transparency channel is preserved in the end result and didn't affect the resulting colors from quantization). The third and fourth are what ImageMagick produces with RGB and Transparent colorspace settings (large sections of the opaque areas are converted to transparent, and the 4th color is used for transparency; resulting colors are darker overall).

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the channels and explicitly selecting the channels for which to reduce the colours, then re-combining channels, might be a way to go:

```
convert UmRGOCs.png -separate -channel RGB -colors 4 +channel -combine out.png
```

[image]

Comment: This came close to it, but the final image ends up with a much higher color count. Attempting to reduce it again leads to the same problem of the background noticeably affecting the selected colors. I noticed though that it fills the transparency with a sort of average image color, and worked from there. Bit too long to explain the line in a comment, so I'll post it as an answer as it produces a result for the image that is very similar to that produced by GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of [Mark Setchenll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26100166/401746), I noticed his command strips the transparency and replaces it with a color based on the image's contents but increases the color count. Working from that, I found that overlaying the original image over the result allowed me to then reduce the color count without the resulting colors being noticeably different because of the transparency. The original alpha channel is then copied over from the original image to produce a result that is very similar to what is produced by GIMP.

```
convert emblem.png ( +clone ( +clone -separate -channel RGB +dither -colors 4 +channel -combine ) +swap -flatten ) -channel A -threshold 50% +swap -compose CopyOpacity -composite +dither -colors 5 test.png
```

The final reduction is one larger to account for transparency, and produces a color palette similar in count and colors to those from image editors for this image.

[Comparison Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtuHq.jpg)

1. Original
2. GIMP
3. `convert UmRGOCs.png -separate -channel RGB -colors 4 +channel -combine out.png`
4. `convert emblem.png ( +clone ( +clone -separate -channel RGB +dither -colors 4 +channel -combine ) +swap -flatten ) -channel A -threshold 50% +swap -compose CopyOpacity -composite +dither -colors 5 test.png`